# How can I find the number of partial orders given n elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

I understand that there does not exist any generalized formula while anti-symmetric and reflexive relations can be found out by formula. Also Bell's Triangle can used for number of equivalence relations.

So how can one find the number of partial order relations for a finite set of elements?

Comment: You want either [A000112](http://oeis.org/A000112) or [A001035](http://oeis.org/A001035), depending on whether you consider your elements distinguishable. (E.g. on two elements $\{1,2\}$, is the order $1<2$ the same as the order $2<1$, or is it a different order?)

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the source. Can you explain how these are calculated also?

Comment: If you think I know something that OEIS doesn't, then that's very nice of you to say so, but it's very much not true. If they don't list a good way of calculating it, then a good way probably isn't known. I have no idea how they came up with those numbers, but there ought to be some information in at least one of the papers they reference.